# Record the userID/Name in Sharepoint form?

Tags: sharepoint, digital-signature

I have Sharepoint List data that I need certain people to confirm is accurate, and I want the form to record the name of the person who clicked the "I approve" button. Is this possible? So something like (appologies for psuedo-code)

```
 Button_OnClick
 Me.VerifiedOn=Date()
 Me.VerifiedBy=NameOfUser ' <-- This is what I need
end sub
```

Ideally I'd want to implement some sort of digital signature (We all have PIV cards), but I think that requires plugins that I don't have access to (Government system).

Answer (score 1):

You answer will depend on your form.

If you're using an InfoPath form, then put some rules on your button to set "ApproverField" to userName().

If you're using something in JS, you can do so directly:

```
var fuv = new SP.FieldUserValue();
fuv.set_lookupId(_spPageContextInfo.userId);
sharePointListItem.set_item('ApproverField', fuv);
//now proceed with the rest of the save
```

This isn't possible in a default SharePoint form, but you could have a workflow. Run on change, then, in pseudocode:

```
If Status equals "Approved"
and ApproverField is blank
    Update item (AppproverField = ModifiedBy)
```